# Google charts title is mis-aligned

Tags: google-visualization

This validates ok `http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=600x500&chxt=x,x,y&chds=0,8&chxr=2,0,8|0,0,3&chxl=0:|0|1|2|1:|Hover%20cursor%20over%20day%20number%20for%20calendar%20date&chxp=0,0.5,1.5,2.5&chtt=Here+is+your+chart,+as+requested&chdl=values&chdlp=t&chd=t:4|6|8&chof=validate`

if we remove the trailing `8&chof=validate` which requests validation, that leaves

`http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=600x500&chxt=x,x,y&chds=0,8&chxr=2,0,8|0,0,3&chxl=0:|0|1|2|1:|Hover%20cursor%20over%20day%20number%20for%20calendar%20date&chxp=0,0.5,1.5,2.5&chtt=Here+is+your+chart,+as+requested&chdl=values&chdlp=t&chd=t:4|6|8`

and when we look at it we see that the text starts somewhere off the left of the image.

Any ideas?

---

Answer:   my `chxp`  (x-axis position) parameter was wrong.

this works (although I might want to indent that second axis more)  `&chxp=1,0|2,0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have &chxt=x,x,y
Shouldn't this be &chxt=x,y ?
I've tried this, looks okay:
`http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=600x500&chxt=x,y&chds=0,8&chxr=2,0,8|0,0,3&chxl=0:|0|1|2|1:|Hover%20cursor%20over%20day%20number%20for%20calendar%20date&chxp=0,0.5,1.5,2.5&chtt=Here+is+your+chart,+as+requested&chdl=values&chdlp=t&chd=t:4|6|8`

Comment: +1 for trying. I have `&chxt=x,x,y` because there are two x-axes one for the day number and one for the text (note, instead of day number I will later have a row for day on month, a row for month, so I definitely need - at least - two x-axes).

Comment: also, I notice that your solution leaves one text which I intend as x-axis to the left of the chart. This is bad a s it steals area from the chart and max chart size is very small (max 30,000 pixels, so probably 500x600 or 400 x 750)

Comment: How about this: This would shift the chart to right to make room for the label: "&chxp=0,0.5,1.5,2.5|1,0" (note the extra |1,0 at the end).

Comment: +1 thanks for trying, but unless I cut & pasted wrongly. I see no difference with http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=600x500&chxt=x,y&chds=0,8&chxr=2,0,8|0,0,3&chxl=0:|0|1|2|1:|Hover%20cursor%20over%20day%20number%20for%20calendar%20date&chxp=0,0.5,1.5,2.5|1,0&chtt=Here+is+your+chart,+as+requested&chdl=values&chdlp=t&chd=t:4|6|8

Comment: See updated question for the answer. You didn't get it right, but no no else even tried, so you get awarded the answer

Comment: @Mawg Your link in the comment has &chxt=x,y instead of &chxt=x,x,y that's why it's no different. Try this: [chart.apis](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=600x500&chxt=x,x,y&chds=0,8&chxr=2,0,8|0,0,3&chxl=0:|0|1|2|1:|Hover%20cursor%20over%20day%20number%20for%20calendar%20date&chxp=0,0.5,1.5,2.5|1,0&chtt=Here+is+your+chart,+as+requested&chdl=values&chdlp=t&chd=t:4|6|8)